# Multiple replace with special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to refactor some code:

```
const newValue = value
  .replace(/\{1\}/g, '<i class="ms ms-1 inline"></i>')
  .replace(/\{2\}/g, '<i class="ms ms-2 inline"></i>')
  ... etc etc
return newValue;
```

I would prefer not to use `replace` each time.

---

I have been trying the following without success:

```
const mapObj = {
  '/\{1\}/': '<i class="ms ms-1 inline"></i>',
  '/\{2\}/': '<i class="ms ms-2 inline"></i>',
  ...
}
const reg = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).join("|"), "g");
return value.replace(reg, (m) => mapObj[m]);
```

For simple replaces this usually works pretty well, however because of the need to escape the special characters (`{` and `}`) something is clearly going wrong with my regex pattern in the `mapObj` object.

[Here is demo of the current simplified code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fbkwvh?file=index.ts).

How do I go about fixing the pattern (`/\{1\}/`) in the `mapObj` to get the refactored code to work?

Comment: Is the `ms-1`/`ms-2` classname in the replacement really all that's different?

Comment: And is the **pattern** `{n}` the same in all cases?

Comment: Are your cases limited to `{[1-5]}` and `{W}`? Please do not oversimplify, provide the actual requirements.

Comment: At least related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811044/javascript-regex-to-replace-multiple-words-with-new-words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your replacments really are the same other than `ms-1` for `{1}` and `ms-2` for `{2}`, then use a capture group:

```
return value.replace(/\{(\d)}/g, '<i class="ms ms-$1 inline"></i>');
```

The `$1` is the content of the capture group. That expression matches a single digit within `{}`; adjust as needed.

Live Example:

```js
function process(value) {
    return value.replace(/\{(\d)}/g, '<i class="ms ms-$1 inline"></i>');
}

console.log(process("Testing {1} testing {2}"));
```

---

If the replacements vary and you really need to map them, use the function callback:

```
const mapObj = {
    "{1}": "replacement for 1",
    "{2}": "different replacement for 2"
};
return value.replace(/\{\d}/g, m => mapObj[m] || "some default");
```

You could use a capture group to avoid having to repeat `{}` in the keys in `mapObj`.

Live Example:

```js
const mapObj = {
    "{1}": "replacement for 1",
    "{2}": "different replacement for 2"
};
function process(value) {
    return value.replace(/\{\d}/g, m => mapObj[m] || "some default");
}

console.log(process("Testing {1} testing {2}"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your refactor is confusing string, regular expressions, and the escape sequences for both.

Given your code...

```
const mapObj = {
  '/\{1\}/': '<i class="ms ms-1 inline"></i>',
  '/\{2\}/': '<i class="ms ms-2 inline"></i>',
  ...
}
const reg = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).join("|"), "g");
return value.replace(reg, (m) => mapObj[m]);
```

1. The `reg` regular expression will be `/\/{1}\/|\/{2}\//g`, (which is looking for curly brackets surrounded by slashes,) which is not what you want. You want something like `/\{1\}|\{2\}/g`
2. The `(m) => mapObj[m]` won't work as intended, because the `value` string will have words like `"pay {1} to cast"`, whereas `mapObj[m]` is looking for keys like `"\/{1}\/"` (note the slashes around the curly brackets)

What you want to do is remove the unnecessary `/` slashes when converting between Regex and strings and back.

Recommended solution:

```
function magicReplace(value) {
  mapObj = {
    '{1}': '<i class="ms ms-1 inline"></i>',
    '{2}': '<i class="ms ms-2 inline"></i>',
  };
  reg = new RegExp( Object.keys(mapObj).join("|").replace(/\{/g, '\\{').replace(/\}/g, '\\}'), "g");
  return value.replace(reg, (m) => mapObj[m]);
}

magicReplace('Whenever you cast a spell, you may pay {1}.');
//Returns: 'Whenever you cast a spell, you may pay <i class="ms ms-1 inline"></i>.'
```